# Re fade animation not working properly codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Fade animation not working. Call serially is not working as well. If i add only one component to fade, the problem still exists. Here is the video on how it looks in simulator.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mMyhUC6m9Vk

```
public class QuizSplash {

private Form current;
private Resources theme;
Label bb;
Label appleLabel;
Label whiteBgLabel;
Image whiteBg;
Image apple;
int deviceHeight;

public void init(Object context) {
    theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
    deviceHeight = Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight();
    whiteBg = (Image) theme.getImage("whiteBg.png");
    apple = (Image) theme.getImage("apple.png").scaledWidth(deviceHeight / 5);
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    showSplashAnimation();
}

public void showSplashAnimation() {
    Form f = new Form(new LayeredLayout());
    f.setUIID("FormAnimation");
    f.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0x339900);
    f.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);

    whiteBgLabel = new Label(whiteBg.scaledHeight(deviceHeight - 80));
    whiteBgLabel.setUIID("treeLabel");
    whiteBgLabel.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    f.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(whiteBgLabel));
    whiteBgLabel.setVisible(false);

    Container bottomContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    bottomContainer.setUIID("bottomContainer");
    bottomContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.LEFT, 40);
    f.add(FlowLayout.encloseBottom(bottomContainer));

    Container appleContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER, Component.BOTTOM));
    appleLabel = new Label(apple);
    appleLabel.setUIID("apple");
    appleLabel.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    appleLabel.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    appleContainer.add(appleLabel);
    bottomContainer.add(appleContainer);
    appleLabel.setVisible(false);

    bb = new Label(apple);
    bb.setVisible(false);
    bottomContainer.add(bb);

    //text container to fade in at last - update added starts.........................
    quizContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    f.add(FlowLayout.encloseIn(quizContainer));

    TextArea question = new TextArea("Here is the question?");
    question.setVisible(false);
    question.setUIID("Label");
    question.setEditable(false);
    question.setGrowByContent(true);
    question.setGrowLimit(3);
    quizContainer.add(question);

    Container ansContainer = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER));
    quizContainer.add(ansContainer);
    Label yes = new Label("YES");
    yes.setVisible(false);
    Label no = new Label("No");
    no.setVisible(false);
    ansContainer.add(yes);
    ansContainer.add(no);
    //update added ends.........................

    f.show();

    bb.setX(-bb.getWidth());
    bb.setVisible(true);
    bb.getParent().animateHierarchyAndWait(2500);

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            appleLabel.setVisible(true);
            appleContainer.animateHierarchyFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
            whiteBgLabel.setVisible(true);
            whiteBgLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(3000, 0);

        //update added starts...............
        question.setVisible(true);
        yes.setVisible(true);
        no.setVisible(true);
        quizContainer.animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
        //update added ends...........
        }
    });

}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

Update 1: 
 The following code works in simulator but in real devices the apple component fade in is good and other has same problem.

```
    bb.setX(-bb.getWidth());
    bb.setVisible(true);
    bb.getParent().animateHierarchyAndWait(2500);
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {

        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            appleLabel.setVisible(true);
            appleContainer.animateHierarchyFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                whiteBgLabel.setVisible(true);
                whiteBgLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

                Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                    question.setVisible(true);
                    yes.setVisible(true);
                    no.setVisible(true);
                    quizContainer.animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Update 2: 
  The following code doesnt work in both simulator and devices

```
    bb.setX(-bb.getWidth());
    bb.setVisible(true);
    bb.getParent().animateHierarchyAndWait(2500);

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        appleLabel.setVisible(true);
            appleContainer.animateHierarchyFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

    });
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        whiteBgLabel.setVisible(true);
        whiteBgLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
    });
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        question.setVisible(true);
        yes.setVisible(true);
        no.setVisible(true);
        quizContainer.animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
    });
```

Update3:
replacing call serially with flushAnimation doesnt work in simulator and device

```
bb.setX(-bb.getWidth());
bb.setVisible(true);
bb.getParent().animateHierarchyAndWait(2500);
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        appleLabel.setVisible(true);
        appleContainer.animateHierarchyFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

        f.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation(() -> {
            whiteBgLabel.setVisible(true);
            whiteBgLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
            f.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation(() -> {
                question.setVisible(true);
                yes.setVisible(true);
                no.setVisible(true);
                quizContainer.animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Adding flush Animation inside call serially doesnt work in devices

```
bb.setX(-bb.getWidth());
bb.setVisible(true);
bb.getParent().animateHierarchyAndWait(2500);
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {

    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        appleLabel.setVisible(true);
        appleContainer.animateHierarchyFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            f.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation(() -> {
                whiteBgLabel.setVisible(true);
                whiteBgLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
                f.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation(() -> {
                    question.setVisible(true);
                    yes.setVisible(true);
                    no.setVisible(true);
                    quizContainer.animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Update 4:

```
Form f = new Form(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
Label a = new Label(apple);
Label b = new Label(apple);
Label c = new Label(apple);
Label d = new Label(apple);
a.setVisible(false);
b.setVisible(false);
c.setVisible(false);
d.setVisible(false);
f.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(a));
f.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(b));
f.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(c));
f.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(d));

f.show();

a.setVisible(true);
a.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
    Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
        b.setVisible(true);
        b.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

        f.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation(() -> {
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                c.setVisible(true);
                c.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);

                Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                    d.setVisible(true);
                    d.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [ok i have filed an issue here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1785)

Comment: Can you also attach the images to the issue so I can just run it?

Comment: [attached images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ATnICIY2S8UWdQVTlXMVNWcWc)

Comment: You have many undefined variables and access to images that don't compile. Please provide code that compiles and explains which image goes where... E.g. tree...

Comment: ok i have added variables too and all codes. It should compile now. Plz see the video for the issue. For tree label there was a tree image before and since i found the gif is troublesome, i jst put white bg image instead of tree.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't running well for me. I would suggest setting the labels themselves to be visible false and not just their parent containers as a repaint triggered from the label itself might go thru.

Also you can try triggering the animation in the show listener instead of just the `callSerially` this should give the form enough time to appear.

Comment: Didnt the code compile? It did compile for me. Do you want me to share the project itself? At first I tested by setting the labels visibility to false it didnt work so i set its parents visibility to false but same result. And i kept callSerially inside show listener (doesnt work) and also tried showlistener without call serially but no good

Comment: It compiled but I don't see the Apple and only see a part of the blinking. A lot of things aren't clear about what you did e.g. the resolutions for the images etc. and since the code is a bit verbose it's harder to dig thru. I suggest setting all the things that shouldn't show to visible false. 
You have too many things going on at once in this test case so it's hard for both of us to follow the specific issue. I suggest eliminating everything until you find the narrowest possible test case.

Comment: ok i have clear out all unnecessary ones from above question and kept 2 labels that fade. If you dont see apple fade, you can see the white bg fade. They both have same problem (ie blinking before fading). Run it 2-3 times since sometime they fade normally. The white bg is behind apple label but it only fades in after appleLabel fade completes. , so i have used layered layout

Comment: Try:          `appleLabel.setVisible(true);
                appleContainer.animateHierarchyFadeAndWait(2000, 0);
                Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
                    whiteBgLabel.setVisible(true);
                    whiteBgLabel.getParent().animateLayoutFadeAndWait(3000, 0);
                });`

Comment: thankyou shai. what should i do to add new component that fades in after whiteBgLabel fade-in completes? If i add anything it gives same problem as before. I have added the update in the question above

Comment: Just do that after the wrapped code and wrap that too in another callSerially. This lets the EDT flush between the calls.

Comment: hello shai it works in simulator but it has problems in devices. 1 component fade in is good but other has same flashing problem in real devices. I have updated what i have done above. Have a look  if i have done smth wrong.

Comment: That's wrong. The callSerially calls should be nested into one another and should not follow one another.

Comment: I have shown 2 updates above. 1st one has nested callSerially, it works perfectly in simulator but in device, apart from 1st component (ie. appleLabel) , all components have same flashing problem. I think you saw 2nd update (update 2) only.

Comment: Update 1 should be closer to what I'm talking about but you need to isolate the trigger of the flashing. I suggest reproducing this in slow motion mode on the simulator to see if something shows there and analyze it better. Try replacing the two nested callSerially calls with f.getAnimationManager().flushAnimation(...)

Comment: hello shai in slow motion nothing is displayed. If i replace call serially with flush animation for the last 2 components, it doesnt work in simulator & device as well. Its giving me hard time to make it work. Plz kindly look at update 3

Comment: Looking at this again it seems you mixed animate hierarchy and animate layout. I'm guessing that part of the problem is in the clipping the parent container is doing on the underlying layout element. Try flattening the hierarchy as much as possible and using animate layout rather than hierarchy.

Comment: I used animateHierarchy to see if it works but i have also tested using only animate layout.

Comment: Try flattening the hierarchy, it's quite possible the parent containers hide the component rendering.

Comment: sorry... i didnt get you. what do you mean by flattening the hierarchy

Comment: You have containers enclosing the labels that are animated, I think the reason for some of the misbehavior is a conflict between the container paint process and the child paint process. If your labels were directly in the parent container this wouldn't happen. Naturally this makes layout more challenging but lets first try to validate that this theory is correct then figure out how to solve this...

Comment: I tried flattening the hierarchy & I'm not sure if this is the problem. I have updated above what i have tested so far (plz hav a look at update 4).

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas but as a workaround try this. When you call setVisible(true) for the component you want to remain hidden follow in the next line with   `whiteBgLabel.getUnselectedStyle().setOpacilty(0);`

Comment: woooaaa,.... it works.. setOpacity does the magic. Dont know how it works but its great. thankyou